# Why when I register ,the password value ignored in registration function to mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When I made Post request via Postman you can see it in attachment, all data will be send to database(mongoDB) except password value .. Why ? is it hidden or I just miss something?

Update :
I added user model above .

registration function :

```
router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{

//validation joi

registerSchemaValidation(req.body , res);



//check if the user is validated ... 

const emailexist = await User.findOne({Email : req.body.Email});
if(emailexist) return res.send('email is exit , please log in or forget password :)')

//hash the password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const haspassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.Password , salt);
 
const user = new  User({
    Name : req.body.Name,
    Description : 'the best',
    Email : req.body.Email,
    Password : haspassword

});
console.log('hash password : '+ haspassword + " original  : "+req.body.password);
try{
const saveUserData = await user.save();
console.log(saveUserData);
res.json({message : saveUserData})
}catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err)
}
});
```

registerSchemaValidation function :

```
const joi = require('@hapi/joi');
//validation register
const registerSchema = joi.object({
  Name: joi.string().min(6).required(),
  Description:joi.string().min(6).required(),
  Email: joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
  Password: joi.string().min(6).required(),
});
const loginSchema = joi.object({
  Email: joi.string().min(6).required().email(),
  Password: joi.string().min(6).required(),
});

function registerSchemaValidation(data, res) {

  const {
    error
  } = registerSchema.validate(data);
  if (error) return res.send(error.details[0].message);
}
```

User model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    Name: { type: String,
    require:true,
    min:6,
    max:255,
    },
    description: { type: String,
        require:true,
        min:6,
        max:255,
        },

    Email:{
    type: String,
    require:true,
    min:5,
    max:255,
    },
    Passowrd:{
        type: String,
        require:true,
        min:6,
        bcrypt: true
        
        },

        Date:{
            type  : Date,
            default:Date.now


        }

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
```

Postman :
[image: here example]

mongoDB :

[image]

Comment: Try `Password : haspassword()`

Comment: @Triby Its not work  , even if i put "123456789" will not show in database :(

Comment: Please, share the schema definition of the `User` model

Comment: @Tunmee I added it now, Check it please

Comment: There's something fishy about this. There's no mention of a `Date` field in your code, yet _that_ magically appears in your database. Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Comment: @AKX , I think even if you diditnt mention date it will appears in database cus of User model I THINK !  , I followed this toturial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jqok-WgelI&list=WL&index=39&t=0s

Comment: Well, your schema has `Passowrd`, you're passing `Password`.

Comment: @AKX but why not stroing in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema isn't quite a valid Mongoose schema.

- You can't use `min`/`max` with Strings; use `minLength`/`maxLength`.
- It's `required`, not `require`.
- You've misspelled `Password` as `Passowrd`; that's why a property `Password` isn't getting saved.
- There is no property called `bcrypt` I know of.

Try with

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 6,
    maxLength: 255,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 6,
    maxLength: 255,
  },
  Email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 5,
    maxLength: 255,
  },
  Password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 6,
  },
  Date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you you were helpfull , I saw resources they use bcrypt  in Mongoose schema.